# Running Meteor.js. What it means "running first time"?

Tags: docker, meteor, mup

I have created a Dockerfile for creating docker container which can be used to deploy Meteor app using mup.

```
FROM node:8.11.3-stretch
MAINTAINER Pavan Kumar

RUN npm install npm@latest -g
RUN npm install -g mup

RUN curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
RUN export METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' docker_meteor
USER docker_meteor
```

Now I am using above docker image to deploy to my server in bitbucket pipeline

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    release:
      - step:
          script:
            - npm install
            - mkdir .deploy
            - cd .deploy
            - echo $MUP_JS  > mup.js
            - echo $SETTINGS_JSON > settings.json
            - mup deploy
```

Now the problem is at last line, i.e., mup deploy, I am getting following message.

```
This is your first time using Meteor!
Installing a Meteor distribution in your home directory.
Downloading Meteor distribution
```

Downloading Meteor taking lot of time. So I would like to know.

1. What does it means `Downloading Meteor distribution`, while i have already installed Meteor in the Docker container?
2. What should I do in Dockerfile so that docker image is created with all Meteor distribution required run `mup deploy`

Comment: Is it because meteor was installed for the root user and the pipeline runs as `docker_meteor`?
I ended up putting the meteor install into the pipelines cache as well for stuff like packages, which might cover the install part too

Answer (score 0):

I don't use mup but if I had to guess, I'd say that meteor has to be installed in the pipeline script. The dockerfile installs meteor in the docker image but mup may require meteor before it gets to running the docker image (to build it).